# Convert character time format to excel time format in R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following dataframe

`times <- c("00:12:23","00:45:01", "02:13:43") 
 moretimes <- c("00:12:23","00:44:23", "05:12:34")
 x <- as.data.frame(times,moretimes)`

I want to convert all the columns with character time formats into a time format that is excel compatible so I can do sums in excel, I've been trying to us as.Date but am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.ITime` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
times1 <- as.ITime(times)
str(times1)
#'ITime' int [1:3] 00:12:23 00:45:01 02:13:43
```

---

For the updated OP's post

```
x <- data.frame(times,moretimes)
x[] <- lapply(x, as.ITime)
str(x)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ times    : 'ITime' int  00:12:23 00:45:01 02:13:43
# $ moretimes: 'ITime' int  00:12:23 00:44:23 05:12:34
```

Comment: I updated the question so its more applicable to my problem since I'm using dataframes :)

Comment: @yungFanta did you meant `data.frame` or `as.data.frame`

Comment: This works in R but when I export to xls file it does not recognize the column as a time column.